# How to import glue job from one module to another module in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Glue job  resource defined in module A, now I want to import it and use the job name in module B, how can I achieve this?

I tried something like, in the module B:

```
variable "example_glue_name" {
  type = string
}

data "aws_glue_job" "example_glue_name" {
  example_glue_name = var.example_glue_name
}
```

then:

```
module "B"{
source = .....
...
example_glue_name = module.A.example_glue_name
}
```

But I got error: `Unsupported argument, │ An argument named "example_glue_job_name" is not expected here.`, I read the docs here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/glue_script

It looks like terraform doesn't support `data "aws_glue_job"`, it only has something like `data "aws_glue_script"`, but it's not clear how to reference the glue name....

anyone what's the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data source called `aws_glue_job`. The only one that exists is [aws_glue_script](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/glue_script). You would have to create [external](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) data source which would required custom script in bash, for instance, as shown in [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source#processing-json-in-shell-scripts).

The script would use AWS CLI to [get-job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/get-job.html) to query AWS Glue for a job of interest and return its details to your TF script for future processing.

But if module A creates a job, then it should `output` it. Once its output, you can reference in as input to module B.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now, I can just output the name from module A and reference it in a different module, it's quite straightforward, thanks.